# How to create routes group using user nickname

Tags: laravel, routes, laravel-5.7

Now, I've custom routes for show and edit user profile:

**Code:**

```
Route::get('/{nickname}', 'User\ProfileController@index')->where(['nickname' => '[a-z0-9_]+');

Route::get('/{nickname}/edit', "User\ProfileController@edit")->where(['nickname' => ''[a-z0-9_]+''])->name('edit')->middleware('auth');
```

As you can see here in both cases, I use a regular expression and this is a repetition of the code. Also, I have to create many routes that must have a username at the beginning.

**Question:**

So how can I create a group of routers that start with the nickname of an authorized user?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is example creating routes group with dynamic prefix in Laravel:

```
Route::prefix('{nickname}')->group(function () {
    Route::get('/', function($nickname) {
        echo "User nickname: $nickname";
    })->where(['nickname' => '[a-z]+']);

    Route::get('/edit', function($nickname) {
        echo "Edit user with nickname: $nickname";
    });

    Route::get('/post/edit/{id}', function($nickname, $id) {
        echo "User nickname = $nickname and POST ID = $id";
    });

    Route::get('/event/edit/{id}', 'UserController@editEvent');
});
```

Get parameters inside controller method:

```
public function editEvent($nickname, $id) {
    echo "User nickname = $nickname and Event ID = $id";
}
```

**Note:** When you create a new route within a group of routes with a dynamic prefix, you must specify the name of the prefix as a variable in the callback function argument or controller method.